# Nativescript Angular *ngFor first item at last

Tags: javascript, android, angular, nativescript

I dont know whats going on. The index, last and first are correct.
I tried to sort the array in javascript.

#### Versions

@angular/core: 4.1.0
nativescript-angular: 3.1.3
typescript: 2.4.0

#### Expected

```
1234
```

#### Actual Result

```
2341
```

#### Template

```
<Label
    *ngFor="let item of references; let i = index; let last = last;"
    [text]="item.Number"></Label>
```

#### Data

```
references = [  
   {  
      "NodeId":2259,
      "Number":1,
      "Details":"",
      "Url":""
   },
   {  
      "NodeId":7534,
      "Number":2,
      "Details":"",
      "Url":""
   },
   {  
      "NodeId":3585,
      "Number":3,
      "Details":"",
      "Url":"http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18489970"
   },
   {  
      "NodeId":7535,
      "Number":4,
      "Details":"",
      "Url":"http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9701682"
   }
]
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are having? could you please explain more?

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0):

This, does not do any sorting,

```
<Label
    *ngFor="let item of references; let i = index; let last = last;"
    [text]="item.Number"></Label>
```

Inorder to sort you need to create a pipe

Comment: I know that... The array is already sorted server-side. I want to display this array as is. I tried sorting it again via javascript with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `*ngFor` to a wrapping `<StackLayout>`, so:

```
<StackLayout *ngFor="let item of references">
  <Label [text]="item.Number">
</StackLayout>
```

Don't ask why that works, but it probably does.

Comment: Better to you Listview than ngFor

Comment: @MarekMaszay cannot use listview because it should be displayed like "1, 2, 3, 4" and every number is clickable.